# Is "count distinct" exact with BigQuery new standard SQL syntax?

Tags: google-bigquery

With the legacy BigQuery syntax, we have to use the **exact_count_distinct** function if we want to have the exact number of distinct values for a field.

With the [Standard SQL 2011 syntax](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/sql-reference/functions-and-operators), I wonder if "**count(distinct** *myfield*)" will always return the exact number of distinct values if I don't select the 'Use Legacy SQL' option.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`COUNT(DISTINCT input)` gives an exact count in standard SQL.

One important distinction is that `COUNT(DISTINCT input)` is more scalable than `EXACT_COUNT_DISTINCT(input)` in legacy BigQuery SQL, so in general the performance will be better and you are less likely to encounter resource exceeded errors.

You can read about other differences between legacy and standard SQL in the [migration guide](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/migrating-from-legacy-sql).

Answer (score 7):

Based on documentation for [APPROX_COUNT_DISTINCT](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/sql-reference/functions-and-operators#approx_count_distinct) (*with reading in between lines*) :

`COUNT(DISTINCT input)` - exact count
`APPROX_COUNT_DISTINCT(input)` - approximate result